# Bootstrap alignment inputs

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to align vertically all my inputs, how can I do it ?
Cause label can be very long and I want that alignemnt still perfect.
CSS

```
    .span6{
    overflow:hidden;display:inline;
}
.span6 label, .span6 input {
display:inline-block;
}
.span6 input {
    width:70%;
    margin-left:3%;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <form class="form well">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="control-group span6">
                <label for="first-name">Company</label>
                <input class="first-name" type="text" class="input-block-level" />
            </div>
            <div class="control-group span6">
                <label for="last-name">Title</label>
                <input class="last-name" type="text" class="input-block-level" />
            </div>
             <div class="control-group span6">
                <label for="last-name">Country</label>
                <input class="last-name" type="text" class="input-block-level" />
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

JSFIDDLE

http://jsfiddle.net/kY5LL/154/

Answer (score 1):

You should probably read a bit more the [Bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/base-css.html#forms), there is built-in styles for aligning forms horizontally and vertically.

I modified your code to use the horizontal style (`.form-horizontal`).

http://jsfiddle.net/LeBen/kY5LL/156/